# How to print kafka pod logs in JSON format by default

Tags: json, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'am new to k8s, wanted to print kafka pod logs in JSON format by default, without using daemon set.
I found this:

https://gist.github.com/scholzj/2b92fb7389056b7fe1fa2ca8bb3fbdda#file-yaml-my-cluster

But not able to understand how to implement it. I would like to know if there is any other workaround like adding env variable in kafka sts yaml file to print the logs in JSON format by default.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka (or more specifically, Log4j 1.x) doesn't have any included functionality to do JSON logging.

The linked file uses a `ConfigMap` to override Kafka's log4j.properties file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: external-logging-kafka
  namespace: myproject
data:
  log4j.properties: |-
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=net.logstash.log4j.JSONEventLayoutV1
    kafka.root.logger.level=INFO
    log4j.rootLogger=${kafka.root.logger.level}, CONSOLE
    log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient=INFO
    log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO
    log4j.logger.kafka=INFO
    log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO
    log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=WARN, CONSOLE
    log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=OFF
    log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=OFF
    log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN
    log4j.logger.kafka.controller=TRACE
    log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=INFO
    log4j.logger.state.change.logger=TRACE
    log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=INFO
```

The documentation for that appender is [here](https://github.com/logstash/log4j-jsonevent-layout), but YMMV because that does not come with Kafka.

Alternatively, you could look at configuring fluentd for multi-line Java stacktraces on its own, then parse those into JSON for downstream log analytics.

Comment: Should I need to mount the volumes, if so please guide me on the same with stateful set?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The repo you have mentioned has everything you need. You should be using https://strimzi.io